# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, indices

Firstly, I want to clear out that I have read and researched about this error generally...and I have read some other questions in stackoverflow. However, they didn't help solve this problem.
The program that I have written is supposed to give you a notification when someone has a birthday(I have the dates in another txt file).However, although when I run the program it works fine until it goes to the last if statement. Then it gives the error that List indices must be integers or slices, not str.

```
import time
import os

with open("file_path") as file:
birthdays = file.readlines()

while True:
    import time
    date = str((time.strftime("%d/%m")))
    for i in birthdays:
        if date == birthdays[i]:
            os.system("""osascript -e 'display notification "{}" with title "{}"'""".format("Someone Has A Birthday Today", "Birthday"))
```

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: You need `date == i` because `i` is not an index.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do is call `os.system` once for each of the birthdays that occur today. The following is what you should be doing:

```
date = str((time.strftime("%d/%m")))
for i in birthdays:
    if date == i:
```

When you `for`-`in` loop or iterate over a list, you get the items in the list, not the indexes of the items. You don't need another subscription.